# Anaconda Navigator - using "conda install -c anaconda keras" installs incompatible tensorflow-dependencies

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

Using Anaconda Navigator (2.1.1),
creating a new environment via

```
conda create --name myenv1
```

and trying to install keras via

```
conda install -c anaconda keras
```

yields in

- tensorflow 2.1.0
- tensorflow-base 2.1.0

being installed, alongside with

- tensorflow-estimator 2.6.0,

resulting into the infamous
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘tensorflow_core.estimator‘" in Python.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or, why is compatibility not assured?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please :

```
pip install -U tensorflow-estimator
```

Could you please use the later 2.x versions as many bugs are fixed, please try tf 2.6/2.7 and let us know.
you may also refer to similar issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28976)

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed, very appreciated. I see, I should have been more specific with my question. It was not about an "issue" with tensorflow. In fact, I am using pip when working on the LINUX-cluster at the institution I am affiliated with. Though, for courses and seminars, I would like, tailored to the (novice and Windows-)audience, to use "Anaconda Navigator". In my understanding, using "Anaconda Navigator" with "conda" and "anaconda" were to assure package-compatibilities. I seemed to have found a _workaround now, though, it is pretty clumsy, in particular, not straightforward.